# django - Passing data to view without a form

Tags: django-views, handsontable

I'm using Hansontable to allow users to create a matrix of input variables.  How do I pass this matrix back to my views.py without it being part of the input form?  I can add a form field for a 2-dimensional array, but I don't actually need it since the hansontable is creating the "input field".

I need to compute a set of results using the matrix before echoing it back to the user along with the results and storing it in a bd.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do pass any data to a backend without using a HTML form (without refreshing the page) you have to utilize AJAX methodologies/practice. Using jQuery you can do this like so:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/some/url",
  data: JSON.stringify(<handsontabledom>.getData())
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Also note there is a tutorial on the Handson Tables documentation all about saving the data via a ajax request.

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.19.0/tutorial-load-and-save.html

Comment: Thanks.  I sorta knew that AJAX would play a role because as you mention that's how the tutorial passes data back to the db.  I guess the piece that didn't get is that the data would be available to any backend function not necessarily just a straight submission to the db.

Comment: A Form submission or ajax request simply means passing data over to the backend. You can manipulate this data, use this data to lookup new data, or insert the data into a database; it doesn't really matter what you do with the data but the technical pieces of it is that you need to submit (transmit) the data from the front end to the backend and the only 3 ways to achieve it. 1) form submission 2) ajax 3) url parameters (causes a refresh of the page)